# How to use prepared statement using entity framework with MYSQL DB?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-5, prepared-statement

I have been trying to incorporate prepared statements into my application which is using EF 5.0. Kindly look at my script below.

```
int parameterValue = 100000;
var addParameters = new List<MySqlParameter>();
var param1 = new MySqlParameter();
param1.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
param1.Value = parameterValue;
param1.ParameterName = "user_id";
addParameters.Add(param1);
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"delete FROM tbl_user where user_id = @user_id", addParameters);
```

it produces this error

```
Exception: {"Fatal error encountered during command execution."}
InnerException: {"Parameter '@user_id' must be defined."}
```

so based on InnerException description i changed the parameter nae to "@user_id"

```
int parameterValue = 100000;
var addParameters = new List<MySqlParameter>();
var param1 = new MySqlParameter();
param1.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
param1.Value = parameterValue;
param1.ParameterName = "@user_id";
addParameters.Add(param1);
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"delete FROM tbl_user where user_id = @user_id", addParameters);
```

but still the same error.

What could i be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

==============================================
Additional info

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="MySql.Data" version="6.7.4" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="MySQL.Data.Entities" version="6.7.4.1" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using EF I think you should use something like this:

```
int parameterValue = 100000;
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"delete FROM tbl_user where user_id = {0}", parameterValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me just show you good practice code that show what you want + recommendation on resource releasing:

```
using (SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand()) //release good practice
{
    comm.CommandText = "delete FROM tbl_user where user_id = @user_id";
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text; //can be skipped for your case
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@user_id", SqlDbType.Int)).Value =
        parameterValue;
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: but im using EF, shouldnt i be using db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand?

Comment: Well, you can safely replace SqlCommand with DbCommand. But actually if you would look at class hierarchy(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx): then you can see that SqlCommand is inherited from DbCommand. If you deal with some real abstraction - then better use DbXXX, but you explicitly specify SQL.  Keep in mind explicit better than implicit

Comment: i stumbled upon a blogpost saying that i should add this in the connection string which i did and finally i wasnt encountering the errors anymore

`Allow User Variables=True;`


now my problem is that there are no errors anymore but the records do not get deleted...

`int parameterValue = 2;
var addParameters = new List<MySqlParameter>();
var param1 = new MySqlParameter("@userid", parameterValue);
addParameters.Add(param1);
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete FROM tbl_user where user_id = @userid", addParameters);
db.SaveChanges();`

no errors but no deletion occurs

Comment: doesnt work
`int parameterValue = 2;
var addParameters = new List<MySqlParameter>();
var param1 = new MySqlParameter("@userid", parameterValue);
addParameters.Add(param1);
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete FROM tbl_user where user_id = {0}", addParameters);
db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: doesnt work also
<br>
<br>
`int parameterValue = 2;
var addParameters = new List<MySqlParameter>();
var param1 = new MySqlParameter("@userid", parameterValue);
addParameters.Add(param1);
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete FROM tbl_user where user_id = {0}", addParameters);
db.SaveChanges();`
no
`int parameterValue = 2;
var param1 = new MySqlParameter("@userid", parameterValue);
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete FROM tbl_user where user_id = {0}", param1 );
db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: this one works



`int parameterValue = 2;
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("delete FROM tbl_user where user_id = {0}", parameterValue 
db.SaveChanges();`